# find npm package folders

Tags: regex, bash, npm

I am trying to get a list of all dependencies of a given npm package.

Given the following hierarchy:

```
 1. ./node_modules/@dependency-group/dependency1/package.json
 2. ./node_modules/dependency2/package.json
 3. ./node_modules/dependency2/node_modules/dependency3/package.json
```

Desired result:

```
@dependency-group/dependency1
dependency2
dependency3
```

I wrote the following script (Should be executed in project root dir):

```
find -iregex '\.\/(node_modules\/((@[^\/]+\/)?[^\/]+)\/)+package\.json' -printf '%h\n' | awk -F'/' '{tmp = $(NF-1)"/"$(NF); module = gsub("node_modules/","",tmp); print tmp}' | grep -v "*"
```

Explanation: find any of variations, get path without 'package.json' node, get last and one before last paths. if the one before last node is 'node_modules', remove it, else if it's a package group keep it.

But There is a problem in the regex.

If I change it to a more basic one it partially works:

```
find -iregex '\.\/node_modules\/[^\/]+\/package\.json' -printf '%h\n' | awk -F'/' '{tmp = $(NF-1)"/"$(NF); module = gsub("node_modules/","",tmp); print tmp}' | grep -v "*"
```

result: `dependency2`

in JS the regex works fine:

```js
const regex = /\.\/(node_modules\/((@[^\/]+\/)?[^\/]+)\/)+package\.json/gi;
const str = `./node_modules/@dependency-group/dependency1/package.json
./node_modules/dependency2/package.json
./node_modules/dependency2/node_modules/dependency3/package.json`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    console.log(m[0]);
}
```

How to make the regex fit find command?

Comment: Why not use https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-ls, or the lock file?

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe. Based on your comment i made it. Could you post it is an answer: `npm ls -parseable | awk -F'\' '{tmp = $(NF-1)"\\"$(NF); print tmp}' | sed 's/node_modules\\//'`.

Comment: There is no need to pipe awk through to sed. You can use the gsub function on tmp to do the same thing. npm ls -parseable | awk -F'\' '{tmp = $(NF-1)"\\"$(NF); gsub("node_modules "," ",tmp);print tmp}'